# react native : Display an Accordion inside modal returns an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, modal-dialog

In my example I am trying to display Accordion but I get the following error:

> "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with
> the same orientation because it can break windowing and other
> functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead"

I would be happy for some ways to solve this.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Modal, 
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Accordion } from "native-base";

export const EarthquakeModal = ({ setModalVisible, modalVisible }) => {
  const dataArray = [
    { title: "First Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
    { title: "Second Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
    { title: "Third Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }
  ];
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
      <Modal animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}>
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
      
        <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content padder>
          <Accordion dataArray={dataArray} expanded={0}/>
        </Content>
      </Container>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: try  listMode="SCROLLVIEW"

Comment: i didnt get you, where to put it ? its looks not works

Comment: can you share working snack code i can fix it

Comment: ok, i fixed that. i used with some other lib and its works .